# Why does tracing C# code in Linux fail when imported into speedscope?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, visual-studio-code, profiling

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a bit of code which is running very slowly, so it was suggested that I profile the code to find out why.

The following image shows Visual Studio Code running on Linux and I have used a few dotnet commands below to create the `trace.nettrace` and `trace.speedscope.json` files:

[image]

I then try to import the `trace.speedscope.json` file into https://www.speedscope.app/ and I get the following error:

[image]

---

**COMMANDS:**

I used the following page as a guide to create the trace speedscope files:

https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/wiki/Importing-from-.NET-Core

To be specific, the command I used was:

`dotnet trace collect -p <process id> --format speedscope`

---

**EXAMPLE:**

An example generated speedscope trace file can be seen here:

https://pastebin.com/4WW2tbiF

---

**QUESTION:**

How do I create a speedscope trace file which works with https://www.speedscope.app/ ?

Comment: Does `click here to load an example profile` works for you on https://www.speedscope.app/ website? Can you upload some example trace file (`trace.speedscope.json`) to internet?

Comment: @osgx, yes the example profile works fine.  I have uploaded an example trace file here: https://pastebin.com/4WW2tbiF

Comment: Your error message is `Importing as speedscope json file. Failed to load format Error: Tried to leave frame "*" while frame "*" was at the top at`, some related issues: https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/1206 https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/1178

Comment: @osgx, based on those links, it seems the reporter is waiting for a new version to be released with the fix.  Seems I will  have to wait for the new released before I can start profiling my app.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Older version of speedscope, downloaded from https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/releases/download/v1.5.3/speedscope-1.5.3.zip did work for me to open your trace json file. 5 threads are visible, with 4, 5 or 7 seconds of trace log. Don't understand anything. But in web console I have "speedscope v1.5.3 Importing as speedscope json file import: 207ms - timer ended" from speedscope.75eb7d8e.js +  import.a03c2bef.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commands (based on [manual](https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/wiki/Importing-from-.NET-Core) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdDo5.png):

```
$ dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace
$ dotnet trace collect -p <process id> --format speedscope
No profile or providers specified, defaulting to trace profile 'cpu-sampling' 
Provider Name Level Enabled by 
Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler Informational(4) --profile 
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime Informational(4) --profile 

Process: /Code/mysql-insert-1234/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/mysql-insert-1234 
Output File: /Code/mysql-insert-1234/trace.nettrace

[00:00:00:02] Recording trace 2.0604 (MB) 

Press <Enter> or <Ctrl+C> to exit... Trace completed.
$ dotnet trace convert --format speedscope trace.nettrace 
Writing: /Code/mysql-insert-1234/trace.speedscope.json 
Conversion complete
```

Your error message from [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX5dM.png) (similar error reproduced from your raw json file):

```
speedscope v1.8.0  
Importing as speedscope json file 
Failed to load format error: Tried to leave frame "AppendExtraBuffer" while frame "TryGetValue" was at the top at 31.8
 at n._leaveFrame (160)
 at n.leaveFrame (160)
 at speedscope.js:166
 at a (166)
 at speedscope.js:166
 at Array.map (<anonymous>)
 at s (166)
 at import.js:111
 at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
 at s (import.js:111)
```

Based on "Error: Tried to leave frame" fragment of error I was able to find two report of similar errors:

https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/1206

> dotnet-trace: Error in speedscope.app showing with Failed to load format Error: Tried to leave frame #1206 Closed
> mcraiha opened this issue Jun 6, 2020
> ...
> josalem commented Jun 17, 2020
>
> Looks like this is an error caused by a recent change in Speedscope (jlfwong/speedscope#273) that decided to change behavior and fail hard on some ordering constraints. I'll take a look at our logic for conversion over in Microsoft/PerfView and see if I can figure out what causes the ordering issue.
>
> Issue in Microsoft/PerfView: microsoft/perfview#1178.
> Based on the comments here, it looks like we should be able to fix this by picking up the newest TraceEvent version.
>
> adamsitnik commented Jun 18, 2020
> I've provided a fix [microsoft/perfview#1212](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/pull/1212)
>
> noahfalk closed this in #1313 Jul 6, 2020

and

https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/1178

> Export to speedscope sometimes has asymmetrical open/close frame event sequencing #1178  Open
> jlfwong opened this issue May 23, 2020 · 8 comments

So the error is said to be connected to https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/pull/273 update of speedscope ("jlfwong merged 2 commits into master from jlfwong/fail-unmatched-loudly May 23, 2020") [which was included](https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/tags) into v1.6.0 (May 31, 2020) version of speedscope.app. I can recommend you to try earlier version of speedscope to parse this file (v1.5.3 from Jan 16, 2020) or to get newer version of perfview (with https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/pull/1212 commit applied).

There are precompilerd offline versions of speedscope app: https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/releases - get the version before pull/273 update from https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/releases/download/v1.5.3/speedscope-1.5.3.zip

Unpack it, open index.html with browser and load your json trace file. I was able to render your example from https://pastebin.com/4WW2tbiF with that older version of speedscope

Don't know how to use npm or update microsoft/perfview or use non-released version of microsoft/perfview.

Comment: TraceEvent 2.0.57 & PerfView 2.0.57 should include the microsoft/perfview/pull/1212 commit  - https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/releases. They are packages as nupkgs, and newer dotnet-trace (https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-trace, https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/releases) may include them. Don't know how to update musical packages of microsoft and their libs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  The precompiled version worked perfectly https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/releases/download/v1.5.3/speedscope-1.5.3.zip